Parity violation via symmetry breaking?
(Apologies in advance for a poorly formulated question.) In Physics, if something can be equally well found in state A or state B, but for whatever reason is in state A, we sometimes observe the phenomenon of symmetry breaking. We're not surprised that a ball stays in one of the minima of the $-x^2+x^4$ potential, because it should've randomly chosen some possibility; same for the Mexican hat potential.
Are there any known proposed mechanisms explaining the left/right neutrino parity violation by considering some field whose potential's minima correspond to the presence of "left" and "right" interactions? This could be smth like $Z_2$ symmetry breaking or picking up a random value on a Mexican hat.
